# Sockets program exits upon accept

Tags: c, sockets

For some inexplicable reason, this C++ program exits upon accepting a socket. The socket is accepted, that is reflected on the client end, but the server then spontaneously explodes.

The full code follows:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 500
#define BACKLOG 50

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage %s port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    struct sockaddr_storage theiraddr;
    socklen_t addrlen;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    theiraddr.ss_family = AF_INET;

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);

    if (sockfd == -1)
    {
        printf("Sock Error!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Bind Error!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1)
    {
        printf("Listen Error!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    addrlen = sizeof(theiraddr);
    int accepted;

    for ( int i = 0; ; i++ )
    {
        usleep(100000);

        errno = 0;
        printf("pre-accept\n");
        accepted = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&theiraddr, &addrlen);
        printf("%i", accepted == -1); //this line does not get executed

        if(errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            printf("WOULDBLOCK %i\n", i);
            continue;
        }
        else if(accepted == -1)
        {
            printf("TERRIBLE TRAGEDY\n");
        }

        printf("Accepted.\n");

        char msg[] = "You have connected.";

        send(sockfd, msg, sizeof(msg), 0);

        close(accepted);

    }
    close(sockfd);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be C++.

Comment: What happens? "spontaneously explodes" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: The server "explodes"? Can you give us some details?

Comment: Despite the fact that it will crosscompile between C++ and C, the issue occurs when compiled under both languages. And, the title explains further. The program simply closes.

Comment: Well, what gets printed? And if you change `printf("%i", accepted == -1);` to `fprintf(stderr, "accept: %i\n", accepted);`?

Comment: what is the last thing printed on the server side?

Comment: Why are you sending `"You have connected."` on `sockfd`? Since *spontaneously explodes* isn't a very helpful description, are you getting a SIGPIPE?

Answer (score 2):

You are not seeing error messages since you don't have a `\n` at the end of the format string.  `stdout` is line buffered. In any case use `stderr` for error output.

Your real error seems to be this one

```
send(sockfd, msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
```

I guess you meant to send on `accepted`, the file descriptor that `accept` provided to you for doing the communication.

Comment: Checking the return value of send() could have been useful, if not informative, too :-)